# Kendo UI DropDown list inside a Kendo Grid problems

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using Durandal JS framework, and Kendo UI.

In my grid, I want both portfolioName andm InstrumentName to display the text field, but when I hit the SAVE event below I want to pull the ID field.

The problem I have now is when I go to INSERT mode and choose from the instrument/portfolio DropDown lists, it populates the grid with the ID; however I want the TEXT to show. For example, InstrumentId vs. InstrumentName.

I have a grid defined in my ViewModel code as follows with some DropDown editors:

```
positGrid = $("#positGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,         
        columnMenu: false,
        toolbar: [
            { name: "create", text: "Add" }
        ],
        columns: [{
            field: "id", hidden: true,
        },
        {
            field: "portfolioName", title: "Portfolio Name",
            editor: portfolioDropDownEditor, template: "#=portfolioName.name#"
        },
        {
            field: "InstrumentName",
            width: "220px",
            editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=InstrumentName#",
        },
           save: function (e) {             // inline row save event                 
            InsertUpdatePos(e)
        },
     });
```

Here is the dropdown editor function :

```
      // PULL PORTFOLIO LISTING FROM SERVER AND DISPLAY IN DROPDOWN LIST
function portfolioDropDownEditor(container, options) {

    var pfItems = [{         // FOR TESTING ONLY...
        "pfName": "1"
    }, {
        "pfName": "2"
    }];

    //var input = $('<input id="portfolioName" name="portfolioName">');
    var input = $('<input required id="portfolioName" data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id"> data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" ');
    input.appendTo(container);

   // debugger;


    input.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "/api/breeze/GetPortfolios"
            },
            pageSize: 6,
        },
        optionLabel: "Choose a portfolio",
    }).appendTo(container);
}
```

I'm using this kendo sample as a guide but still can't get it working :http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

thanks.
Bob